# innodb DEPENDENT SUBQUERY very slow

Tags: mysql, innodb

Here is some innodb table. It `insert,update,query` very frequently.

`tn` is product id

`col` is product sub id

`tindex` is product description.(store by each word)

`date` is product add date stored by `strototime('now')`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `tn` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `col` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
  `tindex` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(10) NOT NULL,
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `tn` (`tn`),
  KEY `tindex` (`tindex`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How I want to query some products which sub id contains words 'anticorrosive' and  'waterproof'

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable a
WHERE tindex =  'anticorrosive'
AND EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM mytable
WHERE tn = a.tn
AND col = a.col
AND tindex =  'waterproof'
)
ORDER BY DATE
LIMIT 10
```

full table is neally `12,700,000` lines, `1.1GB` ,it cost `4.8356s`, explian the query get

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY a   ref tn,tindex   tindex  92  const   1173    Using where; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  mytable ref tn,tindex   tn  47  production.a.tn 161 Using where
```

And here is `my.ini`,

```
[mysqld]
character_set_server=utf8
skip-external-locking
skip-networking
key_buffer = 256M
tmp_table_size = 128M
max_connections = 1024
wait_timeout=10
back_log = 2048
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 2M
table_cache = 2048
table_open_cache = 1024
sort_buffer_size = 8M
read_buffer_size = 4M
net_buffer_length = 92K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 256M
thread_cache = 512
query_cache_size= 256M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 192M
ft_min_word_len=2
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

How to speed up the query? re-do the index? query code? or change some value in `my.ini`

**UPDATE 1**
I have tried change index kye, and my table still grow up, now it has neally `20mln` lines `2.2GB`

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE INDEX (tn,col,tindex);
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX (date);
```

query 1

```
SELECT A.* FROM 
(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE tindex='words1') A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT tn,col FROM mytable WHERE tindex='words2') B
USING (tn,col) order by date limit 10
```

using 29.6278s

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    15674   Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY <derived3>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1716    Using where; Using join buffer
3   DERIVED mytable index   NULL    date    5   NULL    13918039    Using where; Using index
2   DERIVED mytable index   NULL    date    5   NULL    13918039    Using where; Using index
```

query 2

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE tindex IN ('words1','words2')
GROUP BY tn,col HAVING COUNT(1)=2 order by date limit 10;
```

using 23.8711s

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  mytable index   NULL    date    5   NULL    19359399    Using where; Using index; Using temporary
```

Comment: I would try an index on `(tindex, tn, col, date)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes:

- Why is there no `PRIMARY KEY` in the table?
- Why `date` is of type `int` and not `date` or `datetime` or `timestamp`?
- Why is it called `date` when it stores date and time?

Regarding the actual question, the efficiency of the query, an index on `(tindex, tn, col, date)` would help in my opinion much more than the other suggestions. And since you have no primary key and the `(tindex, tn, col)` is unique (you have added another unique index), my suggestion is:

- (optionally) drop that unique index)
- define the primary key as `(tindex, tn, col)`:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE mytable
    DROP INDEX __the_name_of_the_unique_index,  -- this is optional
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (tindex, tn, col) ;
  ```

This will take some time (that's why I suggest you do both operations in one pass.)

Then you can measure your query and all the suggested rewritings of the query (and check if the primary index is used).

- Why is this a better index?

Because the `tindex` column is the first column in the index, all the rows with `tindex='anticorrosive'` will be in consecutive pages in the index (and all the rows with `tindex='corrosive'` will be in another part of index but still in consecutive pages.) So, reading (scanning) these 2 parts of the index will be much faster than scanning the whole table or scanning the whole index twice (which is what mysql does essentially with the `(tn, col, tindex)` index.)

Another benefit of making this index the primary key is that you get rid of the (hidden) 6-byte column that InnoDB added and has been using as the clustered index of the table (since you did not provide any primary or unique constraint/index) so the table is now less wide. The `(tindex, tn, col)` will be the clustered index of the table from now on. That also means that the `date` values will be available for the query - after the 2 parts of the index have been scanned.

Comment: great! I droped unique index. `ALTER TABLE mytable ADD PRIMARY KEY (tindex, tn, col) `; and `ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX (date);`. Now i only have `2 indexes`. then use the same query, only `0.0052 s`. I try to change any other search words, all of them below `0.1s`. Make a right index is such important that cause different effection. I will Sstill test for a long time to see if it will cause another problem then mark a right anwser. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use JOIN

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable a
JOIN
mytable b
ON b.tn = a.tn
AND b.col = a.col
WHERE b.tindex =  'waterproof'
AND a.tindex =  'anticorrosive'
ORDER BY a.DATE
LIMIT 10
```

Also a composite `index(tn,col,tindex)` will help.

Comment: a bitter faster, `4.0612s`, hope it would cost under 1s. thanks.

Comment: Did you add the index?

Comment: i added `alter table mytable add index myindex (tn,col,tindex)`, but still slow.. sometimes some query words would cost 87.6206s.

Comment: The `JOIN` is ok - but only if the `(tn,col,tindex)` combination is unique. Otherwise it may return duplicate results (while the original will not.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches

## Approach #1 : DITCH CORRELATED SUBQUERY

You should ditch the correlated subquery and replace it with the JOIN of two subqueies

```
SELECT A.* FROM 
(SELECT * FROM mytable  WHERE tindex='anticorrosive') A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT tn,col FROM mytable  WHERE tindex='waterproof') B
USING (tn,col);
```

Depending on the number of products, this will be a long query anyway.

## Approach #2 : DITCH JOINS ALTOGETHER

```
SELECT tn,col FROM mytable
WHERE tindex IN ('anticorrosive','waterproof')
GROUP BY tn,col HAVING COUNT(1)=2;
```

This should be more like it (Less Overhead)

## CAVEAT

Please add this index

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE INDEX (tn,col,tindex);
```

This will make sure every (tn,col) only has unique tindex values.

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: thanks for your anwser. I have added `ALTER TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE INDEX (tn,col,tindex);`, `ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX (date);` the query still slow. see the `explain` in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is already well performed by mysql, because the `rows` column means mysql get exactly what rows(1173 & 47) it has to work with.

**Your problem is ORDER BY:**

To fix that try to up `sort_buffer_size` to 1024M

[ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Also try another indexes, unique: (tindex, date) or (date, tindex)